# Switch On bluetooth programmatically on iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth

I just want to know whether is it possible to switch on bluetooth programmatically on iPhone?

Comment: That's a very general question - at this point in time, you can use Bluetooth for GameKit (multiplayer games) and wireless headsets. iPhone -> non-iPhone sending of data is not supported. You can however use GameKit to send data to other iOS devices.

Comment: since you've changed your question: GameKit will enable Bluetooth once the dialog for connection pops up and Bluetooth is selected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it is possible to switch on/off the Bluetooth by using the below lines of code , but since it access private frameworks of Apple, your App may reject in App store push

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
    exit( EXIT_SUCCESS ) ;
#else
    /* this works in iOS 4.2.3 */
    Class BluetoothManager = objc_getClass( "BluetoothManager" ) ;
    id btCont = [BluetoothManager sharedInstance] ;
    [self performSelector:@selector(toggle:) withObject:btCont afterDelay:1.0f] ;
#endif
    return YES ;
}

#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
#else
- (void)toggle:(id)btCont
{
    BOOL currentState = [btCont enabled] ;
    [btCont setEnabled:!currentState] ;
    [btCont setPowered:!currentState] ;

}
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason David Schiefer answered your question as two comments, so I'm just gonna repeat what he said:

> That's a very general question - at this point in time, you can use Bluetooth for GameKit (multiplayer games) and wireless headsets. iPhone -> non-iPhone sending of data is not supported. You can however use GameKit to send data to other iOS devices.
>
> since you've changed your question: GameKit will enable Bluetooth once the dialog for connection pops up and Bluetooth is selected.