# corebluetooth framework

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, iphone-3gs

I have implemented a application to check whether bluetooth is ON/OFF using CoreBluetooth.framework but when i run that application on my iphone 3GS device it shows that the device does not support bluetooth low energy. please anybody help me with this or just a hint about any other bluetooth APIs that supports for iphone 3GS also appreciable.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

CoreBluetooth framework is only available in iOS 5.0+ and the hardware for Bluetooth 4.0 is only currently included in the iPhone 4S, iPhone 5 and the new iPad.  Your 3GS does not have the necessary hardware to support the CoreBluetooth framework calls which is why you get the message you get.

Comment: Ya i got to know about it through google. Anyways thank you for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you want to use private API on your app, but in case you can the `BluetoothManager` is a simple API and can do what you need...
Here is [a link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6606814/1349444) that can help you.
Other than that it's not possible using public API so far...

Answer (score 0):

Core Bluetooth only works on BLE module (Bluetooth 4.0). iPhone 3GS was released in 2009 while BLE standard was released in 2011. Even though iPhone 3GS could run iOS 6.0, it still cannot work with CoreBluetooth.